# Refreshing data in Bulk on ElasticSearch: Bulk update/removal vs indexing from scratch with alias

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a source of data that provides the latest snapshot of documents (and not a diff). I would like the same snapshot to reflect on elasticsearch for searching. I have the following options to do the same:

1. Fetch everything from elastic (using scroll) and calculate diff in memory and bulk update (bulk API with index action) the same - this will require the program to hold twice as much memory to calculate diff
2. Bulk update (bulk API with index action) everything from the snapshot and fetch everything that wasn't updated to elastic (search API with filter on UIDs and last updated) and make another bulk request to soft delete the diff (bulk API with update action) - slightly better than 1) as we don't need to download a lot of data from elastic, just the diff
3. Keep two indices on elastic with an alias, one as current "searchable" copy, and the other as a stand-by for updates. Whenever a new snapshot comes in, we can use the stand-by one to `[delete all documents][1]`, bulk update everything in the snapshot to the one on stand-by and flip the alias (alias API - atomic in nature) to updated one so that the latest is searched.

Note: The diff is supposed to be very small.

How does approach 2 compare with approach 3 in terms of performance cost and space efficiency of elastic?

Comment: How many records/documents are we talking about?

Comment: About 30k records, but I would really like to understand how the performance is impacted if the data is scaled up, let's say, to 100k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is clearly the least performant both in terms of memory requirements and computing needs. You'll need to 1) query all records from your primary data source, 2) query all records from Elasticsearch, 3) figure out the diff and 4) bulk update all records in Elasticsearch again. As time goes, your primary data source will always contain approximately the same number of records, but the number of records in ES will grow since you have new records in your snapshot that are not in Elasticsearch and also records that will need to be deleted from Elasticsearch, which means that step 2 above will retrieve more and more documents each time.

With option 2 you'll need to 1) query all records from your primary data source, 2) bulk index them, 3) then query Elasticsearch for the records that weren't updated and 4) bulk update them in Elasticsearch again. This is not my preference either for the same reason as for option 1, i.e. your Elasticsearch index will keep growing.

Option 3 is the closest to the ideal solution in my opinion. What I would suggest is that each time you need to index your snapshot, you create a new index, you bulk index your snapshot data and when done you flip the `searchable` alias to the new index. You can also delete the older index since you don't use it anymore.  No need to do a any diff, bulk delete or bulk update anything.

- Day 1:

  - Index1 (alias: `searchable`)
- Day 2:

  - Index1 (can be deleted)
  - Index2 (alias: `searchable`)
- Day 3:

  - Index1 (can be deleted)
  - Index2 (can be deleted)
  - Index3 (alias: `searchable`)

Comment: Growing of data shouldn't happen as we can specify the uid for overwriting the entries.

Comment: Still, the option I described should provide the best performance.

Comment: Is there no downside of creating a new index each time a refresh happens?

Comment: No because you can always delete the older indexes, and the new one is always pristine.